# Factorials and Prime Factors

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I need to write a program to input a number and output it's factorial in the form:

$4!=(2^3)(3^1)$

$5!=(2^3)(3^1)(5^1)$

I'm now having trouble trying to figure out how could I take a number and get the factorial in this format without actually calculating the factorial.

Say given
5
need to get result of
$(2^3)(3^1)(5^1)$
without actually calculating
5!=120.

Comment: It seems that perhaps this would require factoring numbers into prime factors first, which is notably slow.

Comment: I'm writing a program to do this so the slow part shouldn't be a problem. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 17):

If $p$ is a prime, then the highest power $p^k$ of $p$ that divides $n!$ is given by 
$$k=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^3}\right\rfloor+ \cdots.\tag{1}$$

Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function, defined by $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\le x$.

Note that the sum in (1) is a effectively a finite (and usually short) sum: If $p^a\gt n$ then $\lfloor n/p^a\rfloor=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n!=1.2....n$. You are looking for all the primes dividing $n!$. Notice that the only primes that can divide $n!$ are $\leq n$. Now you have to calculate their powers.

For example the "power" of $2$ in $n!$ is $n!/2+n!/4+...$. (Here $n!/2$ means the integer closest to $n!/2$)

Similar formula holds for all other primes as well.

Comment: I'm lost. Could you explain how I could get 5!=(2^3)(3^1)(5^1) without actually calculating 5!=120 using 5 for the example.

Comment: @Bradg89 : The argument is that to calculate the prime powers dividing $5!$, you just have to find the prime powers of $p \le 5$ a prime that divide $1,2,3,4,5$ for each $p$, and then multiply them together. For the prime $2$, $2$ divides $2$ once and $4$ twice ; $3$ divides only $3$ once, and $5$ divides only $5$ once. Thus this gives $5! = (2^1 \cdot 2^2) \cdot (3^1) \cdot (5^1)$. Running the algorithm is essentially factoring the integers from $1$ to $n$. This is the same argument as in André's answer, except that André has smartly made the count for you in advance.

Comment: The only primes that can divide $5!$ are $2$ , $3$ and $5$. Now $\floor{5/2}=2. \floor{5/2^2}=1$. So the power of 2 in your decomposition is $2+1=3$. Similarly $\floor{5/3}=1$, and the power of $3$ in your decomposition is $1$. Same for $5$.

Comment: @voldemort $5$ definitely divides $5!$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Sorry- stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks Patrick your comment made sense of it for me. Now I have to wrap my brain around writing a program to do this.